# Angularjs $http returns error 0

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

Alright so I have an AngularJS application with Laravel 4 as a backend.  The way I want to develop is by running Laravel on a seperate server (via artisan serve) and angular on a seperate one with yeoman assembling all that grunt server for me.

However after trying to get data from the Laravel 4 backend (which serves as a REST api) via Angulars $http all I get is a 0 error message.  Here's my code:

Angular REST service:

```
app.factory('RestService', function($http){
   var restUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/tags';//<-- rest api served with php artisan

   return {
      getResource: function(){
      return $http({method: 'get', url: restUrl})
      }
   }
});
```

Angular controller:

```
app.controller('TagCtrl', function($scope, RestService){
   $scope.getTagList = RestService.getResource()
      .success(function(){
         console.log('Success!');
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
         console.log(data);//<--returns nothing
         console.log(status);//<--returns 0
         console.log(headers);//<-- returns function
         console.log(config);//<-- returns object
     });

});
```

And here is my Laravel 4 routes:

```
Route::get('tags', function(){

      return "This is a temporary message to test routing";

   });
```

Now as all this works if I don't use grunt serve and artisan and put it all in the same folder (angular inside laravels public folder etc.) which I intend to do when I move to production but because I want to minify and do other stuff with grunt before that I want to keep those elements seperate for now.

With some googling I assume the problem is with CORS (cross origin request) but I can't understand how to resolve the issue in this setting.

Comment: Run it in Chrome using Developer Tools. If you the script client/api is on localhost there is no problem of CORS.

Answer (score 0):

try to add $http service in your factory declaration :

```
app.factory('RestService', function($http){
```

Comment: Sorry that missing $http was a typo.  It is in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        $scope.url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/tags';
        $scope.content = [];

        $scope.fetchContent = function() 
        {
            $http.get($scope.url).then(function(result)
            {
                $scope.content = result.data;
            });
        }

        $scope.fetchContent();
```

Also try returning an array of data.
+ return a response code too. For example:

```
return Response::json(array(
    'message' => 'This is a temporary message to test routing'), 200);
```